# I am trying to pass a non-mutable integer argument from one function to other defined functions; what is my mistake?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, parameter-passing, chaining

Suppose I have a chain of function calls.

```
def func1( pick, arg1, arg2 ):
    if pick == 1:
        do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    elif pick == 2:
        do other stuff with arg1 and arg2 
    return stuff that got done

def func2( pick, arg1, arg2, arg3 ):
    if pick == 1:
        do stuff with arg1 and arg2 and arg3 
    elif pick == 2:
        do other stuff with arg1 and arg2 and arg3
    return stuff that got done

def func3( pick, func2, arg3 ):
    if pick == 1:
        do stuff with funcs and arg3
    elif pick == 2:
        do other stuff with funcs and arg3
    return stuff that done
etc ..
```

I was able to pass args from one function to another via SCIPY `quad` (numerical integration) so as to ensure that the args *were not* mutable. I was also able to pass args from one function to another via SCIPY `minimize` (optimization) in which the args *are* mutable. My trouble is in passing the non-mutable input `pick` from one function to another. If I were to place `print(pick)` as the first line of each defined function in the simplified example above, and if I were to call this chain of functions as

```
callme = func3( 2 , func2(pick = pick, args) , [6, 0.5] )
```

then my code would eventually spit out an error message that reads

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

but first it would do something like:

```
1
2
1
2
2 # (from pick = 2 in func3)
[6   0.5]
```

How/Why is this happening, and is it possible to send the input `pick` from one function to another in a chain of function calls?

Edit: My guess would be passing pick as an object of a class, or using kwargs, or passing pick as an unpackable tuple consisting of a single element; but I'm not sure if this is correct or how to implement this. Ideally, there is some operation I'm unaware of that is as simple as `callme = func3( pick.func2 , func2, [6, 0.5] )`. I've tried declaring `pick` as `global`, but this results in an error-message about a parameter being global.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `pick` as an input from every function but left it as a variable in the functino. I then placed the following code before the function chain to initialize `pick`.

```
def selectdist(pick):
    ## 1 for original representation
    ## 2 for normal representation on semilog(x) axis
    ## 3 for normal representation on linearly-spaced ln(x) axis
    return int(pick)

pickdist = selectdist(3) # choose 1 2 or 3
```

After the function chain, one run the function chain using a re-initialized `pick`. Since it no longer is an argument that is passed from the top of the function chain on down, the source of the bug is gone.