# Converting find() in matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing

I am converting a code from Matlab to Python. The code in Matlab is:

```
x = find(sEdgepoints > 0 & sNorm < lowT);
sEdgepoints(x)=0;
```

Both arrays are of same size, and I am basically creating a mask.

I read [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html/) that nonzero() in numpy is equivalent to find(), so I used that. In Python, I have dstc for sEdgepoints and dst for sNorm. I have also directly put in lowT = 60. So, the code was

```
x = np.nonzero(dstc > 0 and dst < 60)
dstc[x] = 0
```

But, I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Sheet Counter\customsobel.py", line 32, in <module>
    x = np.nonzero(dstc > 0 and dst < 60)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I read about the usage of a.any()/a.all() [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472814/use-a-any-or-a-all), and I am not sure how that will work. So, I have two questions:
1. If it does, which array to use?
2. If I am correct and it does not work, how to convert the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` does boolean operation and numpy expects you to do bitwise operation, so you have to use `&` i.e

```
x = np.nonzero((dstc > 0) & ( dst < 60))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`np.argwhere()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)
 (and note the importance of the () around the inequalities):

```
>>X=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>Y=np.array([7,6,5,4,3])
>>ans = np.argwhere((X>3) & (Y<7))
>>ans 

array([[3],
   [4]])
```

Comment: This does work, but sorry I can't upvote as my reputation is not enough. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all -- I was there too. Glad you have a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it yourself like:

```
x = [[i,j] for i, j in zip(sEdgepoints , sNorm ) if i > 0 and j < lowT]
```

Will give you a list of of lists corresponding to your the matching constraints.
I guess this might not be exactly what you are looking for.

Maybe look at the pandas module, it makes masking more comfortable than plain python or numpy:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html