# Matplotlib xtick gives "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data using matplotlib. The problem is when I am using plt.xtick() function it gives me following.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Below is the code error is at line no 60 "plt.xticks(np.array([r + barWidth for r in range(len(ener))]), xlab, rotation=90)"

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import math
import os, pdb

paths=["1leo_5fpps_pwat", "1leo_5fpps_u8", "1leo_5fpps_u8_t4"]
aminoacids = {1:"Ser1", 2:"trp2", 3:"thr3", 4:"trp4", 5:"glu5", 6:"gly6", 7:"asn7", 8:"lys8", 9:"trp9", 10:"thr10", 11:"trp11", 12:"lys12"}
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
replica=0
f, ax = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(15,10), sharex=True)
for i in range(3):
    xf=np.random.rand(6000, 199)
    Z = np.mean(xf, axis=0)

    # set width of bar
    barWidth = 0.25

    # set height of bar
    ener = Z[1::3]
    vdw = Z[2::3]
    elec = Z[3::3]

    filtered_index=np.where(ener<25)
    ener = ener[filtered_index]
    vdw = vdw[filtered_index]
    elec = elec[filtered_index]


    ax[i].set_title(paths[i])
    # print(Z.shape, ener.shape, vdw.shape, elec.shape)
    # print("Z\n", Z)
    print("vdw\n", vdw)
    print("electrostatic\n", elec)
    print("Total\n", ener)
    print("sum\n",vdw+elec)


    # Set position of bar on X axis
    r1 = np.arange(len(ener))
    r2 = [x + barWidth for x in r1]
    r3 = [x + barWidth for x in r2]

    # Make the plot
    ax[i].bar(r1, ener, color='red', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='ener')
    ax[i].bar(r2, vdw, color='green', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='vdw')
    ax[i].bar(r3, elec, color='blue', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='elec')
    ax[i].legend()
    xlab = np.array([(i,j) for i in range(1,13) for j in range(i+1,13)])
    xlab = xlab[filtered_index]
    xlab = np.array([[aminoacids[i], aminoacids[j]] for i,j in xlab])

pdb.set_trace()
f.suptitle('Interaction energy of Trp-zipper replica {}'.format(replica), fontsize=16)
f.text(0.5, 0.02, 'Native contacts', ha='center', fontsize=16)
f.text(0.08, 0.5, "Energy (kcal/mol)", va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=16)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.25)
plt.xticks(np.array([r + barWidth for r in range(len(ener))]), xlab, rotation=90)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-2]], visible=False)
plt.ion()
plt.show()
# plt.savefig("{}/plots/inter_ener_trpzip_{}.png".format(os.environ["root"], replica), bbox_inches='tight')
# plt.pause(5.0)
# plt.show()
```

few months back this was working but now it is giving me error. I dont know why xtick gives the above error.

I have read about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34472814/5202279) and this error occurs when there is some decision making statement based on array so why is xtick producing this error.

Comment: It would be useful if you could point to the line which causes this error.

Comment: edited the post to include line number which gives error. so line 60 gives error.

Comment: it seems that xlab is an array with shape (66, 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```py
plt.xticks(np.array([r + barWidth for r in range(len(ener))]),[ ''.join(x) for x in xlab] , rotation=90)
```

The problem here is that

```py
plt.xticks(A,B)
```

expects B to be a list of strings.

But you were feeding B as a numpy array of 66 x 2 instead.
So we join the 2 elements together with the

```py
''.join()
```

function and iterate over the 66 with list comprehension.

Comment: This seems to work. Can you provide a bit of explanation.